# Function parameters or arguments in JavaScript/Node

Tags: node.js, function, parameters, arguments

**Here is the full code first -**

```
function printDir() {

  var filter = fs.readdir(dir, function callback(err, list) {

    if (err) {

      console.log('an error has occured.');

    };

    list.forEach(function (file) {
      if (path.extname(file) === '.' + ext) {
        console.log(file);
      };
    });

  });
};

printDir();
```

Okay so I'm having a hard time understand how the (file) part is working. I've poked around multiple places including MDN but I must be either having a brain fart or am missing something with functions. Can someone point me to a resource or answer basically what is (file) doing and where did it come from, lol, in the following (from above) -

```
list.forEach(function (file) {
          if (path.extname(file) === '.' + ext) {
            console.log(file);
```

Is it an argument? parameter? User made? Built into the JavaScript core? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

file is the argument that the function being passed to forEach takes.  It might be easier to reason about when it's written this way:

```
var logFiles = function (file) {
  if (path.extname(file) === '.' + ext) {
    console.log(file);
  };
}

list.forEach(logFiles);
```

Comment: Thank you! I did a little reading into arguments, and also went back in the code and changed (file) to (hotdog) to see it still works. I didn't realize exactly how arguments work and found this Thanks AGAIN!!!     _Arguments are Passed by Value
The parameters, in a function call, are the function's arguments.

JavaScript arguments are passed by value: The function only gets to know the values, not the argument's locations.

If a function changes an argument's value, it does not change the parameter's original value.

Changes to arguments are not visible (reflected) outside the function._

Answer (score 0):

File is the file object that you get when you iterate over list via the forEach method.  list comes from the function called by fs.readdir.

It's a very common pattern in javascript to pass a result to an argument to a callback function.